# How do i keep only the last 2 folders and delete all others in a directory?

Tags: linux

I have a directory containing several folders like that:

```
/
   20170901150843
   20170902123221
   20170903203423
   20170904123245
   20170905115432
```

I would like to delete all directories and keep only the last 2 ones. (The 2 newest)

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it:

```
ls -Fd DirPath/20*|grep '/$'|head -n -2|while read -r d; do rm -rf "$d"; done
```

This works as follows:-

- `ls` lists in name order entries in `DirPath` beginning with `20`.
- The `-F` option classifies the files with a trailing character, which is `/` for directories.
- The `-d` option lists directory names, not their contents.
- `grep` ensures that files which are not directories are excluded.
- `head` copies all the lines except the last two.
- `while read -r d` assigns the variable `d` to each directory in turn.
- For each directory `rm -rf` removes it.

Notes:-

- I recommend that you put `echo` before `rm` while testing, to make sure you are removing the directories you want.
- You may need to elaborate the mask if there are other directories beginning with `20`, eg `20[1-9][0-9][01][0-9]*` or something even more detailed.
- You could use `xargs rm -rf` instead of the `while` loop: this will work in your case, but I have allowed the technique to be extended to the more general case where there may be embedded spaces in the names.

Answer (score 0):

If they are named that way, this will work.

```
find . -maxdepth 0 -type 'd' | sort -r | tail -n +2 | while read line; do rm -rfv "$line"; done
```

Explanation:

1. Find directories in current working directory
2. Sort their names in reverse order (important for next step)
3. Read all but the first 2 lines of input to the output
4. Remove (recursively, forcibly, and verbosely) the entry(in this case directory) with the name matching each line of input

Comment: Bad idea... check out the `-maxdepth` argument for `find`. This will currently match on all directories under the current working dir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's *always* good to be explicit with what you're trying to do.

```bsh
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | \
    grep -vE '\./(20170904123245|20170905115432)' | \
    xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 0):

I would produce that 1 column list of directory names into a file named bb.out for example. Edit the file and remove the 2 directories you want to keep. Be sure to remove those 2 directories. Then create and edit a new file say aa.out. In aa.out put many lines containing just rm -f  You can do this quickly and easily by typing 5 lines of rm -rf and then use copy once and paste many times to make aa.out have as many or more lines as bb.out. Now just type`paste aa.out bb.out > cc.out`  Now just source cc.out and it will remove all your files. cc.out will just contain n number of lines of `rm -rf filename`.